# iOS AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool: How to use videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithAdditionalLayer

Tags: ios, xcode, avassetexportsession

I'm struggling to find any documentation on how to use videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithAdditionalLayer. I've been using videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer, but it does not support HDR videos.

If anyone could provide an example, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any hints?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing yet!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add layer instructions in addition to animationTool

CMPersistentTrackID trackId = [asset unusedTrackID];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* effectlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstruction];
[effectlayerInstruction setTrackID: trackId];
[effectlayerInstruction setOpacity:1.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];

videoInstruction.layerInstructions = @[effectlayerInstruction, videolayerInstruction]; //effectlayerInstruction should be first to not overlap by the video, make layer with bgColor clear

/// animationTool:
composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithAdditionalLayer:layer asTrackID: trackId]; //trackId should be the same